# Undefined variable in functions.php file

Tags: php

I'm new to php and I'm trying to figure out why the following error is occurring:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: post in functions.php on line 59
```

Here is my functions.php code:

```
<?php

// related pages
function wpb_related_pages() {
    $orig_post = $post;
    global $post;
    $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);

    if ($tags) {
        $tag_ids = array();

        foreach($tags as $individual_tag)

            $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;

            $args=array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
            'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
            'posts_per_page'=>4
            );

        $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<div id="relatedpages"><h3>Related Terms</h3><ul>';

            while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                    <div class="relatedthumb">
                        <a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark"     title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb'); ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="relatedcontent">
                        <h4>
                            <a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                            <p>
                                <?php $content = get_the_content(); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 90, '...');?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"> Read More</a>
                            </p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?
        }
        echo '</ul></div>';
        } else {
            echo "No Related Pages Found:";
        }
    }

    $post = $orig_post;
    wp_reset_query();
}
?>
```

Comment: It i hard to see which line is 59. Can you edit to point to it?

Comment: Please only post the relevant code, not the entire file, and also point to the specific line. You should also properly indent your code properly. It is messy and hard to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a mistake in the function `wpb_related_pages`. Your code should look as below:

**Updated Code with change needed:**

```
// related pages
function wpb_related_pages() { 
# Global $post variable should be called at the start of the function.
global $post;
$orig_post = $post;
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
```

Hope this helps!